# Problem trying to find kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Given this linear transformation:

$f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x + 2y − z + 10w\\2x − y + 3z\\y − z + 4w\end{pmatrix}$.

I want to find its kernel and so I try to solve the following equations system:

[Equations system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC4Ra.png)

Finding the next solution:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5POa.png)

However, the solution appears to be incorrect, as the answer to the problem is that the kernel of the transformation is:

[Real solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u6Dp.png)

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Please use MathJax to type up the question

Comment: There’s no such thing as the “real solution.” *Any* basis for the kernel will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the system could be written as 
$$
f(x,y,z,w)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 10\\
2 & -1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So let $A$ be the matrix 
$$
A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 10\\
2 & -1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To find the null space (Kernel), we should find all vectors such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
That is

\begin{align}
x + 2y − z + 10w &= 0\\
 2x − y + 3z &= 0\\
 y − z + 4w &= 0
\end{align}
Last equation suggests that 
$$z = y + 4w$$
Plugging this equation back we get
\begin{align}
x + 2y − (y + 4w) + 10w &= 0\\
 2x − y + 3(y + 4w) &= 0
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
x + 2y − y - 4w + 10w &= 0\\
 2x − y + 3y + 12w &= 0
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
x + y +6w &= 0\\
 2x + 2y + 12w &= 0
\end{align}
Multiplying equation 1 by a factor of 2:
\begin{align}
2x + 2y +12w &= 0\\
 2x + 2y + 12w &= 0
\end{align}
We get the same equation. This means that we have the following dependence:
\begin{align}
z &= y + 4w \\
x  &= -y -6w
\end{align}
So the kernel is all such vectors $(x,y,z,w)$ such that $z = y + 4w$ and $x = -y-6w$ (which is of dimension 2)

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Both solutions are fine.

Verify that

$$\operatorname{rref} \left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -2& -4& 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \operatorname{rref}\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -6&  0&4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$$